# Codeigniter :How to pass search term in redirect

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, redirect

i have made a simple project with codeigniter using PHP and MySQL. The project gives the abillity to th user to manage his warehouse by adding new product and updating the stock of each one. Now when the user searches for a product and updates the stock value, the app updates the database and refreshes the page and showing all the products. Is there a way to pass the search term he used or even better the product that he changed in the redirect.
Thanks a lot.

```php
function prevazia($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?login');
        if ($param1 == 'edit') 
        {
            $data['type']    = $this->input->post('type');   
            $data['color']   = $this->input->post('color');
            $addition   = $this->input->post('addition');
            $data['stock']   = $this->input->post('stock') + $addition;
            $data['stock_alert']   = $this->input->post('stock_alert');
            //-----------------------------------------
            include('dbc.php');
            mysqli_query($conn,"SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");
            $sql9 = "SELECT * FROM prevazia_log order by id desc LIMIT 1";          
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql9);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                    $last_id=$row['id']+1;
                }
            }
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
            //$result6 =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            //$additionDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i');
            //$myAdditionDate = $additionDate->format('Y-m-d H:i');
            $log['id']                  = $last_id;
            $log['user']                = $this->session->userdata('name');
            $log['create_timestamp']    = date("d-m-y  h:i:sa");
            $log['type']                = $this->input->post('type');
            $log['color']               = $this->input->post('color');
            $log['previous_stock']      = $this->input->post('stock');
            $log['addition']            = $this->input->post('addition');
            $log['new_stock']           = $this->input->post('stock') + $this->input->post('addition');
            //--------------------
            //$data['role']   = $this->input->post('role');
            $this->db->insert('prevazia_log', $log);
            $this->db->where('id', $param2);
            $this->db->update('prevazia', $data);
            // UPLOAD IMAGE FILE
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', translate('informations_updated'));
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/prevazia', 'refresh');
        }
        if ($param1 == 'delete') 
        {
            $this->db->where('id', $param2);
            $this->db->delete('prevazia');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', translate('data_deleted'));
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/prevazia', 'refresh');
        }
        $page_data['page_name']  = 'prevazia';
        $page_data['page_title'] = 'Πρεβάζια';
        $page_data['prevazia']  = $this->db->get_where('prevazia', array('active'=> $GLOBALS['flag']))->result_array();
        $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);
    }
```

EDIT : the best would be if i could pass the $data['type'] and $data['color'], so when it redirects it will pass these values to the search box.

Comment: pass search term as argument in function in pass in where. and remove `refresh` from redirect as `redirect(base_url() . 'your_controller_and_method/'.$search_term);`

Comment: `your_controller_and_method` is your controller and method

Comment: thanks for your reply, i did this redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/prevazia/'.$data['color']); but got an error. I am using jquery.dataTables.js for the table.

Comment: for datatable search you have to use server side rendering, not passing from url

Comment: how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should return the search param via view,if you are using form submit with method post

```
$data['search_param'] =  $post['search_param'];
$this->load->view('view_page', $data);

<input name="search_param"  value="<?php echo !empty($search_param) ? $search_param : ''?>">
```